# Can we have multiple global.asax in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have mvc4 application, and I also have weapi applicatoin.

Following way I have set up in my IIS
1 website - http://www.xyz.neet is point to D:\Application\Website - this had a global.asax file.
2 added webapplication to above website- http://www.xyz.neet/webapi is point to D:\Application\Website\webapi this has global.asax file and routes to access 
the webapi controller is defined by D:\Application\Website\webapi no routes for webapi at D:\Application\Website leve.

now when I am trying access http://www.xyz.neet/searchresult is working fine,
but when I am trying to access http://www.xyz.neet/webaip/getproduct giving error like below

```
Physical Path    D:\\Application\Website\webapi\getproduct not found
```

Can this is possible?
Can I we have multiple globla.asax in same mvc4 application? If yes then inner folder global.asax files's RouteConfig routes is valid to register and access smoothly?

Comment: Have you setup the inner webapi folder to be a virtual directory/application?

Comment: @matt_lethargic-yes I have set up application user main website. Any clue?